# How is the Hubble constant $H_0$ determined from gravitational waves?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, gravitational-waves

I’ve already [posted this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36411/) on the Astronomy stackexchange, but now I see I can post it here too (since there is a tag cosmology and the community is larger here). If this isn’t allowed, please remove. Sorry then!

We know there is a discrepancy between the results for $H_0$. On one side there is the method of the Planck mission, where they use the CMB and the Lambda-CDM model to determine the hubble constant. On the other side, they use standard candles, like Cepheids (for example: Riess et al., 2019) and Red Giants (for example: Freedman et al., 2020). The very precise measurements don’t overlap and thus we need a ‘solution’.

One way to improve our knowledge about $H_0$ is by using gravitational waves to determine the Hubble constant (Feeney et al.). They compare the measured ‘strength’ of the gravitational wave with the ‘strength’ of the wave when it was created to determine the distance to the source object. But how do they calculate/determine the ‘strength’ of the wave at the source? I know they also use an EMS observation for calculating the redshift (and that redshift converted to radial velocity divided by the distance gives $H_0$), but from where do they calculate the source-‘strength’ of the gravitational wave? How can they otherwise determine how much energy the wave has lost? I can’t seem to find the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was [already posted on Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36411). Although the question is perfectly on topic here, posting it on multiple sites splits the attention of answerers and readers, and we'd rather have all activity consolidated on one place.

Comment: Okay, I’ll never do it again. I get the reason! Sorry!